# python parent constructor call inheritance

Tags: python, c++, inheritance, constructor

I am new to python and migrating from C++ to python.

```
class B:
   def __init__(self): 
     print "Constructor B was called"
class C(B): 
    def __init__(self): 
     print "Constructor C was called"
c = C()
```

output of the above program is

`Constructor C was called`

expected output

`Constructor B was called 
Constructor C was called`

why parent constructor is not called like it would have been called in C++ .

Comment: In python you must explicitly call super class constructor. Explicit better than implicit.

Comment: If I don't call parent constructor Explicitly. Wouldn't it create problem in object creation?

Comment: From OOP point of view, yes it could have problems, but if you know what you're doing then objects can be created without calling parent's constructor properly. My recommendation is to call parent's constructor always.